# Protected vs package-private in final class

Tags: java

I'll preface this with I believe I understand how the access level modifiers work in Java.  My question has to do with the difference between protected and package-private (no modifier) when used in a final class.

From my understanding:

- If you declare a class as final you aren't able to extend it, which means that there won't be any subclasses of it
- If you don't add a modifier to a method (package-private) it is visible only within its own package
- If you declare a method protected it can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, **by a subclass of its class in another package**

My question is if your class is a final class, is there any difference between package-private and protected?  The final modifier makes it so that there can't be any subclasses, so it doesn't seem like there can be a subclass in another package. Which means that in either case it will just be visible in its own package.

In a final class is there a difference between the two?

If there is no difference is one supposed to be used over the other or does it not matter?

Comment: Where there is no effective difference you are free to use whichever you like. However, `protected` would be a little confusing, since it suggests to the reader that you intend for the class to have subclasses.

Comment: Do not use `protected` unless you intend to have subclasses. The effect on the resulting class is the same (in your case), but it adds noise and confusion for the reader of your source code.

Answer (score 3):

If we apply the *final* restriction (prevent inheritance) to the classical table of access modifiers, we get:

[image: Classic access modifiers table]

So, from the logic point of view (if we study it as a [*Karnaugh map*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map)) **both modifiers *package* and *protected* are equivalent** (if *final* restriction is aplied).

In a second thinking, we can question which one has better performance and which one is closer to the good design principles. Taking into account [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7365441/3714448) of [erickson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3474/erickson), if the final modifier is aplied, both cases should have de same performance at runtime. But from the formal point of view declare it as protected, if it is not possible to inherit, has no sense. So, ***package*** (also called *default* or *without modifier*) **should be de right choose**.

Answer (score 0):

Unless and until it comes to subclassing, there is no difference between `protected` and *no modifier*. Since you are going to restrict subclassing by using `final`, it doesn't make sense to use `protected`, even though it is correct to do so.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If there cannot be any subclasses, there is no advantage in going for `protected` over the default.

However, **`protected` members and constructors will appear in API docs**. This is probably not intended. Fun fact: `java.net.URL` used to have a `protected` methods that was deprecated when replaced by another. Both have now been removed.

In general, make members either `public` (not fields) or `private`.